# How do I find the general equation of a plane?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is anyone able to help me answer the following question?

Consider the plane described by the vector equation

$$(x, y, z) = (2,−1, 3) + t_1(1, 1, 1) + t_2(−2, 0,−1),\ t_1, t_2 \in R$$

Find a normal vector to this plane and hence find a general equation for a plane that intersects this plane at right angles and passes through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

We want a vector $(a,b,c)$ perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and $(-2,0,-1)$. So we need a non-zero solution of the system $a+b+c=0$, $-2a-c=0$.

Pick $a=1$. Then $c=-2$ and $y=1$. So $(1,1,-2)$ works.

Our plane has equation of the shape $x+y-2z=d$. We can now find $d$ using the fact that $(2,-1,3)$ is a point on the plane.